# angularjs: Detect changes to web app and then reload it

Tags: angularjs

Right now when I have changed my AngularJS 1.5.7 application and upload it to the server, I ask the users to clear storage or hard refresh their browser to get the latest version.

Is there a way for the application to automatically detect the check and refresh?

I have been looking on at using [cache manifest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5), but cannot determine if the is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple logic which most of the developers use is adding version param in the script attribute.

For example you have a bundle.min.js script in your application

```
<script src="ui/admin/build/js/bundle.min.js?v=1.2.0"></script>
```

**Note:** you can make this paramter dynamic. 
In this way you will not need to ask for hard refresh or cache clearing etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts here:

> I ask the users to clear storage or hard refresh their browser to get
>   the latest version

1. This means that you did not configure cache correctly. Usual refresh or just opening in new window should be enough. There are several ways of achieving it, e.g. add hash to all your assets, so your index.html (which in this case is configured to be never cached itself) looks like:


   Once you make change, file gets new name, so browser loads it again.
2. While you perform update, user may be logged in and have app opened. In this case to deliver update, you can e.g. add version to index.html and poll version from server once per hour (?) - if you see that newer version is available -- show some popup to user.

But you can also ignore it -- next day user will come back and in most apps will be forced to re-login ;)